# Issue with output for nested std::map

Tags: c++

```
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, std::string>>>mfvs;
```

I want to output the std::string the first part of inner map.

```
for (const auto& iter :mfvs)
{
std::cout << iter.second.first << "\n";
}
```

this gives me an error

Comment: What do you mean by first part? You want only the first string key for the inner map?

Comment: What, specifically, is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iter.second` is an `std::map`, and as such it doesn't have `first`.

If you want to print the first (with lowest key) element (and you are sure it exists), then do this:

```
std::cout << iter.second.begin()->first << "\n";
```

`.begin()` will return you the first element of the `map`, and `->first` will get its key. If you want to print the value of it as well, something along the lines of the following code will work

```
auto firstElem = iter.second.begin();
std::cout << firstElem->first << ": " << firstElem->second.first << ", " << firstElem->second.second << "\n";
```